# How to load new google maps with API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Classic My Maps on maps.google.com will no longer be available.

Now we must use new maps. I would like to embed them to the website, without iframe that google suggests.

Before this change I used simple kml layer:

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&t=m&authuser=0&msa=0&output=kml&msid=212840568890456843825.0004c1fba0c8371a81c2b');";
kmlLayer.setMap(gMap);
```

But during the automatic update of my maps it was broken, if I use the same link - I got empty icons. Here is the new map (converted by google), can I load it using API V3 as I did before?

https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zhJ_pzBRPGN8.kCI6hT4Kq0Ao

---

In other words:
I want to create maps here: https://www.google.com/maps/d/
And to embed them using API v3, but where can I get a link to the layer? Central coordinate, zoom level?

Answer (score 2):

Change the KML Layer link to:
https://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=zhJ_pzBRPGN8.kCI6hT4Kq0Ao&lid=zhJ_pzBRPGN8.kZ0hfyeW-GtI

I grabbed this link from the "Share", "Download KML" URL on the Map that you linked to.

Comment: But I cannot use old icons, they all are <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>